# Devise not redirecting to root path on sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Not really sure why but Devise will not redirect to my root path after a successful sign in.

What happens is I am redirected to the sign in page via `:authenticate_user!` but when I sign in successfully it just refreshes the sign in page.  If I then refresh the page I am taken to root page.  As far as I know I am doing nothin odd with this, just a basic setup for a hobby app.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :feature_documents
  get 'pages/profile'
  resources :memberships
  devise_for :users
  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
  resources :phases
  resources :tasks
  resources :features
  resources :projects
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_breadcrumbs
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :masquerade_user!
  before_action :set_projects

  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :role, :title])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :role, :title])
    # Invitable parameters
    # added_attrs = [:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me]
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
    # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :accept_invitation, keys: [:email]
  end

  def set_breadcrumbs
    add_breadcrumb "Home",     root_path
    add_breadcrumb "Projects", projects_path
    add_breadcrumb "Phases",   phases_path
    add_breadcrumb "Features", features_path
    add_breadcrumb "Tasks",    tasks_path
  end

  private

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
      "auth"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

  def set_projects
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
# This controller is responsible for serving up the static pages for the application
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /
  def home
  end

  # GET /profile
  def profile
  end
end
```

In the console I see the POST but then it just redirects to the sign in page again.

I have used Devise quite a bit, not really sure why this simply will not redirect to root path after sign in even though the sign in is successful.  If anyone can shed some light on the issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the redirect failed. Any error messages from the server log?

Comment: no, there is no error, if I refresh the page the redirect happens, the POST happens in the console but just reloads the Devise sign in page